# Cannot upload symbolic files to Flurry with upload-symbols.py: Broken pipe> <class 'urllib2.URLError'>

Tags: python, flurry

We use upload-symbols.py to upload our app's symbolic files to Flurry according to [this document](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/crash/#symbolication). It works very well for years. 
But recently (since 8th Jan, 2020), it doesn't work with error below (with the argument "--log DEBUG"):

```
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:480  --------------------
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:481  apiKey=R8Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxx672X
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:482  search_path=/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balrog-euxwkknvvkwophatvzhbvvycmlts/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Balrog_DEV/BuildProductsPath/Balrog_DEV-iphoneos
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:483  wait=True
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:484  max_wait=600
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:485  singe_file=False
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:486  connect_archive=False
12:34:44 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:487  --------------------
12:34:44 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:85    fetching project
12:34:45 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:189  project: {u'data': [{u'type': u'project', u'id': u'1210597'}]}
12:34:45 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:88    taring files
12:34:45 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:209  looking for dsyms in /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balrog-euxwkknvvkwophatvzhbvvycmlts/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Balrog_DEV/BuildProductsPath/Balrog_DEV-iphoneos
12:34:45 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:219  Adding Balrog.app.dSYM to tar
12:34:49 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:95    archive: /var/folders/jc/4kbzdvk93n37psbtv72t47xc0000gn/T/tmpllhvXX.tgz (6935104 b)
12:34:49 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:97    creating upload
12:34:50 [DEBUG] upload-symbols.py:278  Created upload {u'data': {u'relationships': {u'project': {u'data': {u'type': u'project', u'id': u'1210597'}}}, u'attributes': {u'uploadType': u'IOS', u'contentLength': 6935104, u'modifiedDate': 1578544422325, u'creationDate': 1578544422325, u'uploadStatus': u'CREATED', u'failureReason': None}, u'type': u'upload', u'id': u'323678'}}
12:34:50 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:100   uploading file
error uploading file. <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe> <class 'urllib2.URLError'>
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

This Flurry-iOS-SDK version is 7.6.6
Please help us what we should do now? Thanks.

```
Updated on 2020-01-15:
```

I update Flurry-iOS-SDK to 10.2.0 in CocoaPods, and then the error is changed as below:

```
15:49:43 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:85    fetching project
15:50:12 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:88    taring files
15:50:16 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:95    archive: /var/folders/jc/4kbzdvk93n37psbtv72t47xc0000gn/T/tmpljqSG5.tgz (6947945 b)
15:50:16 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:97    creating upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Scripts/upload-symbols.py", line 504, in <module>
    main()
  File "./Scripts/upload-symbols.py", line 500, in main
    wait=wait, max_wait=max_wait)
  File "./Scripts/upload-symbols.py", line 98, in find_dsyms_and_upload
    upload = create_upload(project, tar_size, token)
  File "./Scripts/upload-symbols.py", line 276, in create_upload
    response = exec_request(request, "creating upload")
  File "./Scripts/upload-symbols.py", line 421, in exec_request
    return urllib2.urlopen(request, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1201, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 438, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 754, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 641, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError
: ('The read operation timed out',)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My local Python version is python: stable 3.7.6 (bottled), HEAD.

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I sent a mail to Flurry. The script seems to work fine now.